# Retrieved data (date and time) from another backend service is stored incorrectly in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, utc

I'm trying to retrieve json data from another backend service and save it to my own DB locally - to load the data faster from my frontend.
Goal is to represent a graph with this data.

**The procedure is as follows:**

1. **Get data** with the help of axios. (another api backend service)
2. Use Mongoose and its functions to **store it to db**. Here InsertMany.

```
... 
.then(resp => {
Object.insertMany(resp, function(err, docs) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send('Something went wrong. Storing data to db failed.')
          }
          console.log(
            'Successfully stored'
          )
          res.status(200).end()
        })
}
```

3. Store it to MongoDB.

---

**Mongoose Schema:**

```
var ObjectSchema = new Schema({
  consumedQuantity: Number,
  cost: Number,
  body: String,
  date: Date,
  date_download: { type: Date, default: Date },
  product: String,
  unitOfMeasure: String
})
```

---

**Problem:**

I get dates in the following format - from api backend service:

```
{.. "date":"2019-08-08T00:00:00" .. }
```

But stored in MongoDB is something like that:

```
{... "date" : ISODate("2019-08-07T22:00:00Z") ... }
```

How can I fix the problem and where?
I have read some answers but can not translate and use it for my case.
Can I change/modify the Schema?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you change the date in the response to a js Date should work.
Something like this:

```
... 
.then(resp => {
resp.date_download = new Date(resp.date_download); -> If it is an array just loop through
Object.insertMany(resp, function(err, docs) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send('Something went wrong. Storing data to db failed.')
          }
          console.log(
            'Successfully stored'
          )
          res.status(200).end()
        })
}
```

Comment: I need the time and date from the response. 
I have to store this:  {.. "date":"2019-08-08T00:00:00" .. }

Comment: Js date should give you both

Comment: yes i tried in the browser, just to check the output/workflow .. but i have to look up how do it exactly. That means i am not sure yet. Can you give me a hint how you would do it? Thanks

Comment: You should try a database insertion becuase mongoose will do some conversion as well